# TabBar and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

Hi I am new to iOS and I am trying to display a Navigation Controller in a `TabBar` based app.

Here is is what I got:
**H file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

**M file:**

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,viewController5];



    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: but whats your issue..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826125/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-programatically-no-xib-file-or-storyboard/18826179#18826179      Check out this link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding viewController5 to the tab bar controller's view controllers,, add the navigation controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,self.navigationController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: @user2074226, You should accept my answer so other people know that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work.  Mixing the view controllers with the navigation controller gives you view controllers without nav and a nav controller without a view controller.  You need a nav controller for each vc and then create an array of those nav controllers.

Here is an answer that works: [How to add UITabBarController programmatically (no xib file or storyboard)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826125/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-programatically-no-xib-file-or-storyboard/18826179#18826179)