# How to create a "footer section" in UItableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

I know the "footer section" sounds really weird. Let me explain.

When you login to anyone social network app, there would be some sections on the bottom like "News Feed" "Requests" "Friends" and you can select each to go to different section.

Can anyone tell me how to create these sections in a UItableviewcontroller? or what I need is a NavigationController or something?

Comment: Not everyone uses Facebook. Describe what you want without referencing other apps. Do you want a table footer view or do you want a table section footer?

Comment: It is `UITabBarController`. Please check how to create (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826125/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-programatically-no-xib-file-or-storyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one particular way to achieve that UI. But, most common way you can do it is by using UITabBarController as the root or initial view controller and each tab can point to UINavigationViewController or UIViewController. If you do it in storyboard it will be easier to understand at first. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've checked the documentations of UITabBarController. That's actually what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Storyboard you can select your `ViewController`. Then at the top of **xcode** select:

`editor -> embeded - > Tabbar Controller`. It will add tabbar controller for the root of your viewcontroller.